# inserting javascript variable into html output of .innerHTML =

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to insert a variable passed to my function into the output of my .innerHTML = code but do not know how to properly insert it into the HTML output.

```
function playsong(song)
{
    parent.document.getElementById('player').innerHTML = '<object width="199" height="26"><param name="movie" value="audio_player_black.swf"><embed src="audio_player_black.swf?audio_file=upload/'[song]'&color=00000" width="199" height="26"></embed></object>';
}
```

I just get [song] in my HTML output rather than the value of [song]

Not sure how I need to do this properly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

easy:

```
parent.document.getElementById('player').innerHTML = '<object width="199" height="26"><param name="movie" value="audio_player_black.swf"><embed src="audio_player_black.swf?audio_file=upload/'+song+'&color=00`000" width="199" height="26"></embed></object>';
```

just like concatenating any 2 + strings

Answer (score 6):

Instead of:

```
[song]
```

use:

```
 +song+
```

Comment: You'll need to terminate the string beforehand and then reopen it afterward, too.

Answer (score 0):

In place of `[song]` use `+song+`. It's a concatenate function that will add the value.